# Why is this ResourceCollection not working?

Tags: php, laravel

ResourceCollection is not providing a ResourceCollection

I'm trying to provide a collection of my tables to display for a Bulk (index) or all my tables in the database...

There appears to be a bug causing the ResourceCollection to not work, What should I check?

Resource\Order.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Order extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

ResourceCollection is returning this incorrect Json response?

```
// 20191017103310
// http://domain.test/api/middleware/orders/bulkindex

[
  {
    "data": {
      "connection": {

      },
      "grammar": {

      },
      "processor": {

      },
      "bindings": {
        "select": [

        ],
        "from": [

        ],
        "join": [

        ],
        "where": [

        ],
        "having": [

        ],
        "order": [

        ],
        "union": [

        ],
        "unionOrder": [

        ]
      },
      "aggregate": null,
      "columns": null,
      "distinct": false,
      "from": "orders",
      "joins": null,
      "wheres": [

      ],
      "groups": null,
      "havings": null,
      "orders": null,
      "limit": null,
      "offset": null,
      "unions": null,
      "unionLimit": null,
      "unionOffset": null,
      "unionOrders": null,
      "lock": null,
      "operators": [
        "=",
        "<",
        ">",
        "<=",
        ">=",
        "<>",
        "!=",
        "<=>",
        "like",
        "like binary",
        "not like",
        "ilike",
        "&",
        "|",
        "^",
        "<<",
        ">>",
        "rlike",
        "not rlike",
        "regexp",
        "not regexp",
        "~",
        "~*",
        "!~",
        "!~*",
        "similar to",
        "not similar to",
        "not ilike",
        "~~*",
        "!~~*"
      ],
      "useWritePdo": false
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "connection": {

      },
      "grammar": {

      },
      "processor": {

      },
      "bindings": {
        "select": [

        ],
        "from": [

        ],
        "join": [

        ],

     ...

ETC...
```

Please note I can change it to a JsonResource and it works as expected...

EDIT: api.php (route)

```
        Route::get('/orders/bulkindex/', function () {
            return OrderResource::collection(Order::all());
        });
```

EDIT:

```
use App\Http\Resources\Cart as CartResource;

        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'carts' => CartResource::collection($this->carts), // CODE DOES NOT WORK
        ];
```

I get this error message:

```
Property [carts] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Resources\Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Cart extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your route or controller

Comment: @Saly3301 Done, see above!

Comment: is the resource collection class named `Order` or `OrderResource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an Eloquent Model collection to the constructor of the resource directly

```php
Route::get('/orders/bulkindex/', function () {
   return OrderResource(Order::all());
});
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources#resource-collections)

After defining your resource collection, it may be returned from a route or controller:

```php
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
use App\User;

Route::get('/users', function () {
    return new UserCollection(User::all());
});
```

> Do not call the static method `::collection()`

Comment: Where does the first Route go? which file?

Comment: see above... please